# Randomly losing CMD+V (paste) functionality

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am randomly losing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> functionality. Is there a shortcut which might trigger this? So that the keyboard goes into some kind of different mode?

I am working with cmd/shift/option a lot in gfx apps, like Illustrator.

I thought, maybe the <kbd>CMD</kbd>-key is broken, but this happens with both <kbd>CMD</kbd>-keys.

After some time using the system it starts to work again.

I am on Mountain Lion, to which I recently switched, never had this problem prior to Mountain Lion.

Comment: Have you ever created customized shortcuts in the System Preferences? Maybe you have overwritten CMD+V accidently? I know the probability is very low... but maybe?

Comment: @cyphorious thanks for the tip, but as I said, it seems to be triggered somehow. So paste works most of the time, but sometimes not. I double checked, no custom shortcuts in sysprefs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, what I found was that using a Software called ShareMouse, and when it crashed, I lost my <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> functionality; I then forced ShareMouse to close, and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> returned.

You may be experiencing this issue with ShareMouse, or some other piece of software.